# Give Class Name to a Cluster

Tags: vb.net, classification

I have 4 cluster (0, 1, 2, 3) and a number of data from certain class (class 0, class 1, class 2). The data is look like below.

```
(cluster, class)    number of data  

(0,0)                        1  
(0,1)                    2  
(0,2)                    2  
(1,0)                    0  
(1,1)                    0  
(1,2)                    0  
(2,0)                    0  
(2,1)                    0  
(2,2)                    1  
(3,0)                    4  
(3,1)                    3  
(3,2)                    0
```

I would like to give class name to each cluster.

The idea is, the name of certain cluster will be the name of the class in which the number of the data with certain class is the most frequently appear.

I would like to give name to the cluster so the name will be look like below.

Anyone can help how to solve this problem in VB.NET? Thank you

```
cluster class
0            1
1   
2            2
3            0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to create a "custom array object" like this:

```
Public Class DataArray(Of T)

    Public Sub New(rowCount As Integer, columnCount As Integer)
        If (rowCount < 0) Then
            Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("rowCount")
        ElseIf (columnCount < 0) Then
            Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("columnCount")
        End If
        Me.array = New T((rowCount - 1), (columnCount - 1)) {}
        Me.names = New String(rowCount - 1) {}
        Me.rowCount = rowCount
        Me.columnCount = columnCount
    End Sub

    Default Public Property Item(rowIndex As Integer, columnIndex As Integer) As T
        Get
            Return Me.array(rowIndex, columnIndex)
        End Get
        Set(value As T)
            Me.array(rowIndex, columnIndex) = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Cluster(rowIndex As Integer) As String
        Get
            Dim s As String = Me.names(rowIndex)
            Return If((s Is Nothing), String.Empty, s)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.names(rowIndex) = If((value Is Nothing), String.Empty, value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub [Set](rowIndex As Integer, values As T(), name As String)
        For i As Integer = 0 To (values.Length - 1)
            Me.array(rowIndex, i) = values(i)
        Next
        Me.names(rowIndex) = name
    End Sub

    Private ReadOnly array As T(,)
    Private ReadOnly names As String()
    Private ReadOnly rowCount As Integer
    Private ReadOnly columnCount As Integer

End Class
```

So now,  if I create an array of 4 rows `(0,1,2,3)` and three columns `(0,1,2)` of data type `Integer`:

```
Dim data As New DataArray(Of Integer)(4, 3)
```

And to populate some data:

```
data.[Set](0, {0, 1, 2}, "Cluster 0")
data.[Set](1, {0, 0, 0}, "Cluster 1")
data.[Set](2, {0, 0, 1}, "Cluster 2")
data.[Set](3, {4, 3, 0}, "Cluster 3")
```

I can also set the values like you did:

```
data(0, 0) = 1
data(0, 1) = 2
data(0, 2) = 2
data(1, 0) = 0
data(1, 1) = 0
data(1, 2) = 0
data(2, 0) = 0
data(2, 1) = 0
data(2, 2) = 1
data(3, 0) = 4
data(3, 1) = 3
data(3, 2) = 0
```

And to name each cluster:

```
data.Cluster(0) = "Cluster 0"
data.Cluster(1) = "Cluster 1"
data.Cluster(2) = "Cluster 2"
data.Cluster(3) = "Cluster 3"
```